# how to calculate hour difference in 2 decimals behind dot

Tags: javascript, date, time

This is my form:

```
<input type="text" class="date" name="date[]">                      
<input type="text" class="starttime" name="starttime[]">

<input type="text" class="endtime" name="endtime[]">                        
<input type="text" class="hours" name="hours[]">
```

To calculate the hours between `starttime` and `endtime` i use this js:

```
$('.endtime').on('change', function() {      
    //get values
    var date = $('.date').val();
    var starttime = $('.starttime').val();
    var endtime = $('.endtime').val();
      
    //create date format          
    var timeStart = new Date("01-01-2021 " + starttime).getHours();
    var timeEnd = new Date("01-01-2021 " + endtime).getHours();
     
    //console.log(timeStart, timeEnd);
    var hourDiff = timeEnd - timeStart;
    if (hourDiff < 0) {
        hourDiff = 24 + hourDiff;
    }
    
     $(".hours").val(hourDiff);  // output in input field          
});
```

Lets say the starttime is `12:00` and the endtime is `15:45`, the output should be `3.75` but it shows me `3`.
How can i get the hours in 2 decimals after the dot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By not using only the hours in your calculation. You need at least minutes as well, but you may as well use the full resolution of `Date` (milliseconds):

```
// Get the milliseconds-since-The-Epoch values for the times on 01/01/2021
const timeStart = Date.parse("2021-01-01T" + starttime);
const timeEnd = Date.parse("2021-01-01T" + endtime);

// Calculate the difference, divide to get a fractional hours value
let hourDiff = (timeEnd - timeStart) / 1000 / 60 / 60;
if (hourDiff < 0) {
    hourDiff += 24;
}

// Format it to two decimals for display
$(".hours").val(hourDiff.toFixed(2));
```

(`Date.parse` parses the same way `new Date` does, but returns the milliseconds-since-The-Epoch value instead of a date object.)

Note that I've changed the string format a bit (`Year-Month-Day` and a `T` instead of a space) so the string is in [the standard format](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format).

Live example:

```js
function example(starttime, endtime) {
    // Get the milliseconds-since-The-Epoch values for the times on 01/01/2021
    const timeStart = Date.parse("2021-01-01T" + starttime);
    const timeEnd = Date.parse("2021-01-01T" + endtime);

    // Calculate the difference, divide to get a fractional hours value
    let hourDiff = (timeEnd - timeStart) / 1000 / 60 / 60;
    if (hourDiff < 0) {
        hourDiff += 24;
    }

    // Format it to two decimals for display
    console.log(starttime, "to", endtime, "=>", hourDiff.toFixed(2));
}

example("12:00", "15:45");
example("12:00", "03:45");
```

Alternatively, convert the times directly:

```
function toHours(time) {
    const parts = time.split(":");
    const hours = Number(parts[0]) || 0;
    const minutes = Number(parts[1]) || 0;
    const seconds = Number(parts[2]) || 0;
    return hours + (minutes / 60) + (seconds / 3600);
}
```

then

```
// Format it to two decimals for display
let hourDiff = toHours(endtime) - toHours(starttime);
if (hourDiff < 0) {
    hourDiff += 24;
}
$(".hours").val(hourDiff.toFixed(2));
```

Live Example:

```js
function toHours(time) {
    const parts = time.split(":");
    const hours = Number(parts[0]) || 0;
    const minutes = Number(parts[1]) || 0;
    const seconds = Number(parts[2]) || 0;
    return hours + (minutes / 60) + (seconds / 3600);
}

function example(starttime, endtime) {
    let hourDiff = toHours(endtime) - toHours(starttime);
    if (hourDiff < 0) {
        hourDiff += 24;
    }

    console.log(starttime, "to", endtime, "=>", hourDiff.toFixed(2));
}

example("12:00", "15:45");
example("12:00", "03:45");
example("12:00", "3:45");
```

I think if it were me, I'd do that rather than using the `Date` object. It's more direct.

---

You only need those `if (hourDiff < 0)` checks if it's really possible for the end time to be before the start time, but you had them in your original so I figured I should leave them there. You can safely remove them if the end time can't be before the start time.

Comment: `Date.parse("01-01-2021T" + "15:00")` returns NaN in Safari. Perhaps you meant the date part to be "2021-01-01T"?

Comment: @RobG - OMG. Thanks!! I remember something about that string was bothering me at the time but never quite put my finger on it.

Comment: I alreeady did understand that. thx for the solution